# How to get Person instead of Mono<Person>?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

On the retrieve code below, how to get Person instead of Mono or how to get Person from Mono, please ?

[23.2.3 Request and Response Body Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-http-body)

The response body can be one of the following:

Account — serialize without blocking the given Account; implies a synchronous, non-blocking controller method.

[1.7.1. Retrieve](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve)

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.org");

Mono<Person> result = client.get()
                      .uri("/persons/{id}", id).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                      .retrieve()
                      .bodyToMono(Person.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a `Mono<Person>` instance available, you have two choices:

1. compose that reactive type (i.e. use operators available on that type) and use it to save that data in a datastore, serve it as a HTTP response body, etc
2. or call `Person person = result.block()` on it, which *blocks*. So you should not do that in a reactive application because this might completely block the few threads available to your application.